# SharePoint Designer Workflow Create Subsite and Use Parent Top Navigation

Tags: sharepoint-designer, rest, designer-workflow, top-navigation

We have a 2013 Designer Workflow for creating subsites which works fine.

However we want to make it use the top navigation of the parent site.

We're wondering if we can just include a keyword on the requestParameters dictionary which is still unknown for us at the moment (after hours of google-ing)

The requestParameters dictionary items are:

```
__metadata          : Dictionary
Url                 : String
Title               : String
Description         : String
Language            : Number
WebTemplate         : String
UseUniquePermissions: Boolean
```

Does the api accept a parameter like UseTopNavigation boolean or something like that? If yes, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this in your oData which will get the navigation

"Navigation":{"__deferred":{"uri":"https:///_api/Web/Navigation"}}

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/office/dn499819.aspx

Comment: Thanks Nagarajan, however upon checking on your link, the Navigation property is read only. Also, upon going to the link site/_api/Web/Navigation/UseShared, it only shows that this property is set to false, no methods like UpdateUseShared or SetUseShared.